# Como Conectar ao Banco de dados lendo arquivo INI

Tags: delphi-10

preciso fazer o console ler o arquivo ini para tentar conectar ao banco de dados em delphi 10.2

não sei lidar muito com delphi

neste link é metodo aonde está o banco de dados
https://github.com/eantoniobr/LoginServer/blob/master/LoginServer/Database/FiredacPooling.pas

Comment: O método que está no link é o que você criou para tentar conectar ao banco? Você já consegue ler o arquivo .ini? Explique um pouco melhor

Comment: não, meu amigo que fez pra mim lol

Comment: eu quero que método leia o arquivo ini, e faça a conexão com banco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Está é a forma que sei conectar utilizando um `FDConnection`

Mude os dados de acordo com o que você precisa

```
unit FiredacPooling;

interface

uses
  FireDAC.Stan.Intf, FireDAC.Stan.Option, FireDAC.Stan.Error, FireDAC.UI.Intf,
  FireDAC.Phys.Intf, FireDAC.Stan.Def, FireDAC.Stan.Pool, FireDAC.Stan.Async,
  FireDAC.Phys, FireDAC.Phys.MySQL, FireDAC.Phys.MySQLDef, FireDAC.Stan.Param,
  FireDAC.DatS, FireDAC.DApt.Intf, FireDAC.DApt, Data.DB, FireDAC.Comp.DataSet,
  FireDAC.Comp.Client, Classes, IniFiles;

type
  TFireDacPooling = class
    private
      FConnection : TFDConnection;
      function CarregaConfiguracoes(cChave, cSubChave: String; cValorPadrao: string = ''): Variant;
      procedure AtualizarConfiguracoes(cChave, cSubChave: String; cValor: string = '');  
    public
      constructor Create;
      destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

var
  DBPool : TFireDacPooling;

implementation

{ TFireDacPooling }

constructor TFireDacPooling.Create;
{var
  Params: TStringList;}
begin
  {Params := TStringList.Create;
  try
    //Params.Add('User_Name=sa');
    //Params.Add('Password=1');
    //Params.Add('Server=127.0.0.1');
    Params.Add('Server=DESKTOP-3RKGJ2M');
    Params.Add('OSAuthent=Yes');
    Params.Add('Database=Pangya');
    Params.Add('Pooled=True');
    Params.Add('POOL_MaximumItems=1000');

    FConnection := TFDManager.Create(nil);
    FConnection.AddConnectionDef('MSSQLPool', 'MSSQL', Params);

  finally
    Params.Free;
  end;}

  with(FConnection)do
  begin
    if(Connected)then
      Connected := False;
    Params.Values['DriverID']          := 'MSSQL';
    Params.Values['Database']          := CarregaConfiguracoes('ChavePrincipal', 'ChaveSecundaria'); {Pangya}
    Params.Values['User_Name']         := CarregaConfiguracoes('ChavePrincipal', 'ChaveSecundaria'); {sa}
    Params.Values['Password']          := CarregaConfiguracoes('ChavePrincipal', 'ChaveSecundaria'); {1}
    Params.Values['Pooled']            := True;
    Params.Values['POOL_MaximumItems'] := 1000;
    Params.Values['OSAuthent']         := True;
    Params.Values['Server']            := CarregaConfiguracoes('ChavePrincipal', 'ChaveSecundaria'); {DESKTOP-3RKGJ2M}

    Connected := True;
  end;  
end;

destructor TFireDacPooling.Destroy;
begin
  FConnection.Free;
  inherited;
end;

function TFireDacPooling.CarregaConfiguracoes(cChave, cSubChave: String; cValorPadrao: string = ''): Variant;
var
  oConfig: TIniFile;
begin
  Result  := '';               {Carrega o arquivo .ini, mas para isso o mesmo precisa estar no mesmo diretório do EXE}
  oConfig := TIniFile.Create(ExtractFileDir(ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0))) + '\SeuArquivo.ini');

  try
    Result := oConfig.ReadString(cChave, cSubChave, cValorPadrao);
  finally
    oConfig.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TFireDacPooling.AtualizarConfiguracoes(cChave, cSubChave: String; cValor: string = '');
var
  oConfig: TIniFile;
begin                          {Escreve no arquivo .ini, mas para isso o mesmo precisa estar no mesmo diretório do EXE}
  oConfig := TIniFile.Create(ExtractFileDir(ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0))) + '\SeuArquivo.ini');

  try
    oConfig.WriteString(cChave, cSubChave, cValor);
  finally
    oConfig.Free;
  end;
end;

initialization
  DBPool := TFireDacPooling.Create;
finalization
  DBPool.Free;

end.
```

**Editado**

No arquivo .INI existe a Chave e a SubChave como no exemplo abaixo:

```
[CHAVE]
subchave=valor
```

O seu arquivo ficaria +/- assim (Os dados que usei ai são fictícios):

```
[CONEXAO]
Database=Pangya
User_Name=sa
Password=1
Server=127.0.0.1
[OUTROSDADOS]
subOutrosDados=tal
subOutrosDadosDois=
```

Comment: Obgd pela ajuda !

Comment: uma ultima ajuda se possivel, dar pra mostrar como o arquivo ini ficaria ? grato !

Comment: Claro, veja a Edição da minha resposta e se for útil e te ajudou não esqueça de marcar como aceita por favor! :D

Answer (score 0):

```
no seu codigo faltou a namespace "System.SysUtils" se não vai dar erro.
```

dai tentei rodar o .exe rodou, mas não aconteceu nada simplemente fecha sozinho mas acho que não fez conexão. não sei se isso faz diferença

```
[OUTROSDADOS]
```

subOutrosDados=tal
subOutrosDadosDois=

Comment: Não faz diferença estar vazio, se o programa abre e fecha, deve ser algo que você fez errado em seu projeto. Debuggue para ver o que pode ser!

Comment: mudei algumas coisas e funcionou

Comment: Demorei a responder porque como você respondeu sua própria pergunta e não veio notificação para mim... Então quando for assim, ao invés de responder a sua pergunta, utilize a área aqui de comentários ai a pessoa é notificada.